# Get total sum from input box values using Javascript, with decimals

Tags: javascript, html

I copied this from another answer, and it works, but I need to get the two numbers behind the decimal. This rounds...

```
Qty1 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty2 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
Qty5 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
Qty6 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
Qty7 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
Qty8 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>

Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

</script>
```

Comment: try parseFloat https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat instead of parseInt

Answer (score 2):

Replace you script with following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value).toFixed(2);
}
document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Qty1 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty2 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
Qty5 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
Qty6 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
Qty7 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
Qty8 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>

Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))       // parseFloat() instead of parseInt()
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);    // parseFloat() instead of parseInt()
}
document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to change it in both places

Comment: Thank you! What if I only what 2 places behind the decimal?

Comment: use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)  is used for rounding the number

Answer (score 1):

```
function findTotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))       // parseFloat() instead of parseInt()
    tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);    // parseFloat() instead of parseInt()
}
document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `parseInt` use `parseFloat`. And then use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for displaying only 2 decimals.